# What does 'of what' mean here?

Tags: prepositions

Just look at this sentence:

> Numerous studies have been done **of** what a subject can extract from a brief visual presentation.

I am not sure how I should understand **'of'**. I know it's a preposition but, if it is used before **'what'**, how should I understand it?
Can I use **'about'** instead of **'of'**:

> "Numerous studies have been done **about** what a subject can extract from a brief visual presentation?

Answer (score 1):

This is just poor academic style. It means:

- There are many studies which investigate the following question: what can subjects extract from brief visual presentations?

But the style is poor, for various reasons. I would write:

- Many studies have investigated the question of what subjects can extract from brief visual presentation [of stimuli].

The 'academically correct' preposition with *study* here would be *on*, not *of*. Note the difference:

- The study of zoology; the study of language
- A study on the guttural phonemes of Yemenite Hebrew; a study on genetic mutations in seahorse

Answer (score 0):

"On" would be more idiomatic here instead of "of." Either way, it does mean "about," but "studies about" is also not as idiomatic as "studies on."